# Inject dispatcher servlet using Webapplicationinitializer in Springmvc

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc

I have to load dispatcher servlet and its configuration files dynamically. I am looking at the concept of injecting dispatcher servlet using webapplicationinitializer which is a very recent development in spring. The following doc gives an overview:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

I am trying to do a basic setup and its just not working. I am not able to understand where to start swaying away from traditional spring development. Can anyone explain me with an example as to how to use this new mechanism ? I used the following code :

```
 public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
  // Create the 'root' Spring application context
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
    new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

  // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
  container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

  // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
    new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

  // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
  ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
    container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
  dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
  dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}
```

}

Moreover, if we are injecting dispatcher servlet dynamically, does it mean that dispatcher servlet loads during web container (tomcat) startup ?

Comment: I know from experience that `WebApplicationInitializer` works. Can you explain "*just not working*"?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Thanks for the comment. I am not able to setup basic example itself.I have configured ContextLoaderListener in web.xml. It is mentioned in documentation that webapplicationinitializer can be used as normal class. So, I used code mentioned in my first post. If you have any examples to share, can you please let me have a look ?

Comment: @codejammer I updated my answer. You might get some clues from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your mapping from `/` to `dispatcher.addMapping("/*")`.

`/` is already mapped to Tomcat's default Servlet and so `addMapping("/")` won't do anything.

This only applies if you are using Tomcat version <= 14.

On Tomcat start-up, tomcat will look for a class that `implements ServletContainerInitializer`. In Spring, it will find the class `SpringServletContainerInitializer`. This class will be fed a Set of Tomcat loaded classes (basically all your classes). It will then look for any of them that `implements WebApplicationInitializer` and call `onStartup()` on them. That's where the method you posted above comes into play, initializing contexts and Spring's `DispatcherServlet.